# POST request to upload file

Tags: python, django, post, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I want to upload a file to my django application.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload_to_evm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
        file = request.FILES['file']
        filename = FileSystemStorage().save('abcd', file)
        return JsonResponse({'Status': 'Successful'})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/evm_process/', views.upload_to_evm)
]
```

Currently, I am sending my request with `Binary File` option and with header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and it gives `MultiValueDictKeyError` error which means my `request.FILES` is empty and I cannot understand why.

My question are:

1. What is the correct way to make a POST request with all the headers and query_params for the same ?
2. Do I need a parser (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser or FormParser) to upload, save or process the uploaded file ?

Python version: 3.6.9
Django version: 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

1. headers

```
"content-type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------  "
"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token
```

Here you have to set boundary. It is the string to separate the file name and type.

2. You need to import Multipartparser and FormParser.

Hope this help you.